# Extract URL from a html file with regular expression

Tags: r, regex

i am trying to pic the only url /~/ to .ashx wich is within the quots.
from the complete html source file wich i have scraped , i tried the below function to get href match list .

```
processHTML <- function(html) {
  doc <- htmlTreeParse(html, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
  text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
}
```

from the below code snippet i need to pic only excluding the href and qoutations , `/~/media/McKinsey/Business Functions/Marketing and Sales/Our Insights/Discussions in digital Whats a marketing ecosystem/Discussions-in-digital-Marketings-ecosystem.ashx`:

```
href   "/~/media/McKinsey/Business Functions/Marketing and Sales/Our Insights/Discussions in digital Whats a marketing ecosystem/Discussions-in-digital-Marketings-ecosystem.ashx"
```

please help me out with regular expression for above problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question properly then this might help

```r
txt[grepl('.ashx', txt)][['href']]
```

**Output is:**

```
[1] "/~/media/McKinsey/Business Functions/Marketing and Sales/Our Insights/Discussions in digital Whats a marketing ecosystem/Discussions-in-digital-Marketings-ecosystem.ashx"
```

**Sample data:**

```
txt <- structure(c("mailto:?subject=From%20mckinsey.com%3a%20Discussions%20in%20digital%3a%20What%e2%80%99s%20a%20marketing%20ecosystem%20and%20what%20does%20it%20mean%20for%20marketers%3f&body=I%20recommend%20you%20visit%20mckinsey.com%20to%20read%3a%0d%0a%0d%0aDiscussions%20in%20digital%3a%20What%e2%80%99s%20a%20marketing%20ecosystem%20and%20what%20does%20it%20mean%20for%20marketers%3f%0d%0ahttp%3a%2f%2fwww.mckinsey.com%2fbusiness-functions%2fmarketing-and-sales%2four-insights%2fdiscussions-in-digital-whats-a-marketing-ecosystem%3fcid%3deml-web", 
"/~/media/McKinsey/Business Functions/Marketing and Sales/Our Insights/Discussions in digital Whats a marketing ecosystem/Discussions-in-digital-Marketings-ecosystem.ashx"
), .Names = c("href", "href"))
```

Comment: thanks for help but i need to pick the complete url from /~/ till the end .ashx                                                                           "/~/media/McKinsey/Business Functions/Marketing and Sales/Our Insights/Discussions in digital Whats a marketing ecosystem/Discussions-in-digital-Marketings-ecosystem.ashx"

Comment: Isn't the o/p shown above exactly same as what you expect? I would suggest to update your post with the exact i/p (using `dput`) and desired o/p otherwise I am afraid this question will be closed soon ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) link might help).

Comment: it worked . Thankyou so much ...!